# How to save data about deleted records in the django-reversion?

Tags: python, django

In order to save the change history of objects in the database I've started using django-reversion.

But when a record is deleted from the database I cannot see the record in the table changes history.

What could be the problem?

I have not found anything in the documentation. Does this library store the history of deleted data?

Comment: The [docs](https://django-reversion.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) list a feature of the library that you can "Recover deleted model instances". How are you using the library? Have you enabled the middleware or are you making calls to the API from your own code? Add some more information to your question.

Comment: @Tony I have included middleware and put the annotation @reversion.register() on the model. When you change records in the database, data is stored in tables reversion_revision and reversion_version. When you delete a record, it misses the table reversion_revision and reversion_version. Where deleted records will be restored?

Answer (score 2):

As you found out, `django-reversion` does not store records to track deletions.

However, django-reversion has a method [get_deleted](https://github.com/etianen/django-reversion/blob/d89b9f910d1a51719149ea4b7a25477edfd27b72/reversion/models.py#L133) which returns the list of deleted instances of a model. To do so, it lists all objects from the table `reversion_version` and it filters out entries where an entry in `app_<model>` exists.

```sql
SELECT [...]
-- Select all entries from "reversion_version"
FROM   "reversion_version"
WHERE  (
  -- Where the content-type matches the model
  "reversion_version"."content_type_id" = 8
   -- And where the version id
   AND "reversion_version"."id" IN (
     -- Does not match an object where app_<model> still exists 
     SELECT DISTINCT On (V0."object_id" v0."id"
     FROM   "reversion_version" V0
     WHERE  ( V0."content_type_id" = 8
              AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT ( 1 ) AS "a"
     FROM "app_<your model>" U0
     WHERE U0."id" = ( V0."object_id" ) :: BIGINT LIMIT  1) )
) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Having not used django-reversion I set up a project and installed it. After creating a simple model, and creating the [initial revision](https://django-reversion.readthedocs.io/en/stable/commands.html#createinitialrevisions), I added some model instances and then deleted one.

My model table only contains the current data

[image: model table]

Notice `id` 2 is missing, this is the deleted row.

The `reversion_revision` table contains information about when the models were added

[image: reversion_revision table]

and the `reversion_version` table contains the json data representing the objects

[image: reversion_version]

On the admin screen there is a button to recover deleted models, when I click it I'm taken to a screen showing the deleted row

[image: deleted row]

So it would seem there is no specific "delete" record kept, rather a comparison between the reversion tables and your model table is performed and it works out which models have been deleted.